# Git patch from first commit to latest

Tags: git, patch

please is possible to make one "mega patch" from first commit of repo to the latest commit? So, I can download original flies, when I started development and apply that patch and when I compare my repo and this new downloaded original files and patched wit my "mega patch" will be same? Thank you!

I need to see only diffs between first and last commit, not whole patches lined by line in one file

Comment: git diff FIRST..LAST >mega.patch

Comment: this works, but I need to see in my patch only changed lines and files, not full commits line by line, only diffs between first and last commit

Comment: you are using the wrong terminology. I think you would like something like `git log --stat`; but then combined over all commits together?

Comment: I don't understand this command but I need to see changes between first and last commit -> I don't want patch file with all patches but only patch between first and last commit

Comment: That's exactly what you get with forementioned `git diff...`: all changes from the initial state of the working tree to the last one, as if it was a giant single commit. If some files were added or removed in between, the patch will contain appropriate changes.

Comment: please make your question clearer with an example. What do you get as output and what would you like to see as output?

Comment: I would suggest the comment/solution by @user3159253 with one minor modification - leave out the `..` range syntax, and just make it `git diff first last > mega.patch`. That will compute exactly the differences between the `first` commit and the `last`, formatted as a patch file. It does *not* show the incremental patches for each commit. (Note, the range syntax doesn't change this, it just makes it less clear what you're asking for, because, syntactically, it looks like you're looking for a range of something... `git diff` still does exactly the same thing).